# What are the events associated with DOM script load?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I am writing an API that dynamically injects scripts in page. It is thus obvious to target all condition on script load, fail, abort etc.
However, I did not find any documentation that describes event lists for a `<script>`. Only an [MDN document with `load` event example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement).

I initially thought that HTML DOM `<script>` tag is a media element, for which we already have the following event list:

```
onabort
oncanplay
oncanplaythrough
ondurationchange
onemptied
onended
onerror
onloadeddata
onloadedmetadata
onloadstart
onpause
onplay
onplaying
onprogress
onratechange
onreadystatechange
onseeked
onseeking
onstalled
onsuspend
ontimeupdate
onvolumechange
onwaiting
```

If there is a list of events for the `<script>` element that are fired while/before/after the script resource is fetched, please answer.

***Update***:

The 2 events I know that seem to work are `load` & `readystatechange`.

I want to be able to add event listeners when there is no load, or server fails, etc. But I don't know what are the events for them dispatched by Browser.

Comment: Downvoted? why? Any explantions?

Comment: Script elements are not [media elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#media-elements). In HTML only audio and video are.

Comment: @Quentin, yup, thanks. Looks like you got what I want to know. So as media elements have events associated with their content load/error/progress, etc., I want to know the similar events of `<script>` element. (and not hover, focus, etc. of any DOM elements)

Comment: @and-yet These seem to be the event types available as a parameter to .addEventListener. Reading through the list, you should be able to determine what is applicable to <script> tag. Obviously things not related to a form or specific tag? http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-uievents

Answer (score 1):

W3C is the place to go (outside of MDN of course).

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html

Available event types for DOM addEventListener:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-uievents

Comment: Saw that, this is not talking about DOM `<script>` tag, but `script` as **JavaScript to be executed as code**.
How would you have `onfocus` and `onkeyup` events for a `<script>` tag?

Comment: @and-yet Ah the HTML DOM script, which was added in HTML5...will check

Comment: @and-yet Would the answer not lie in the HTML DOM events itself. All being available but linked to a specific tag? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: @DaneBalia, I think the OP is talking about the events related to functionality of the script, like `load`, `error`, `abort`, etc. - while appending the script to DOM. And not generic DOM events.

Comment: @and-yet — [This](http://jsbin.com/fumiwafu/2/) is how you have focus and keyup events on a script.

Comment: @Quentin, why would someone want to do that. I updated my question.

Comment: @and-yet — Why would someone want to make the specification more complicated to implement by throwing a bunch of exceptions over it? "Every element can have a focus event, except scripts because that makes no sense", "Every element can have a tabindex attribute, except scripts because that makes no sense" and so on.

Comment: @Quentin, I am afraid you have still not understood the question. No one is talking about the behavioural JavaScript events here.
Elements like AJAX requests, video/audio elements, etc. have events related to content fetching from server. A user cannot trigger these events. They are triggered based on the current status of the request. So all I want to know is all events while a `<script>` element is fetching a request, and/or after/before that.

Comment: @and-yet — You seem to be trying to differentiate between the script element object which exists in the DOM and the script object which makes the HTTP requests to fetch the remote data. There isn't a difference between them, they are the same object. While `keyup` and `focus` events won't help you solve your problem, you did ask about them in the first comment on this answer and it was to that which I was responding.